# QGraphicsItem shape not working

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5.5

I am creating an application in qt, which should represent figures, which can be grouped, each figure will redefine the shape () of QGraphicsItem, the goal is to have a QGraphicsItem that groups together the figures which does not inherit from QgraphicsItemGroup order you can select the group from the shapes of the other figures it contains, the problem is is that by passing the figures the group does not correctly represent the shape of the figure, an example with QGraphicsRectitem and it worked.

```
class Shape : public QGraphicsObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Shape(QGraphicsItem * _parent = 0 , qreal _width = 75 , qreal _height = 75);

    virtual ~Shape();

    void paint(QPainter *_painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *_option, QWidget *_widget) ;

    QRectF boundingRect() const;

    virtual  Shape * clone();

protected:

    qreal m_width;

    qreal m_height;

    QPen  m_pen;

    QBrush m_brush;

};
   Shape::Shape(QGraphicsItem *_parent, qreal _width, qreal _height):
    QGraphicsObject(_parent),
    m_width(_width),
    m_height(_height),
    m_pen(QPen()),
    m_brush(QBrush(Qt::blue))
{
     setFlags( QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable | QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable );
}

Shape::~Shape()
{

}


void Shape::paint(QPainter *_painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *_option, QWidget *_widget)
{
    Q_UNUSED(_painter);
    Q_UNUSED(_option);
    Q_UNUSED(_widget);
}

QRectF Shape::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(-m_pen.widthF()/2 ,-m_pen.widthF()/2 ,m_width  + m_pen.widthF() , m_height + m_pen.widthF());
}

Shape *Shape::clone()
{
    return NULL;
}
```

> This is the method shape of class Ellipse inherits Shape:

```
QPainterPath Ellipse::shape() const
{
    QPainterPath t_path;
    qreal t_min = qMin(boundingRect().width() /2,boundingRect().height()/2);
    t_path.addEllipse(boundingRect().center(),t_min,t_min);

    return t_path;
}
```

> This is ShapeGroup with the method:

```
void ShapeGroup::paint(QPainter *_painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *_option, QWidget *_widget){
_painter->setPen(QPen());
_painter->setBrush(Qt::cyan);
_painter->drawPath(shape());
if (isSelected()){
    _painter->setPen(QPen(Qt::yellow,5,Qt::DashLine));
    _painter->drawPath(shape());
}}
void ShapeGroup::addToShapeGroup(QGraphicsItem *_shape){
m_path += m_path.united(_shape->shape());
_shape->setParentItem(this);
_shape->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable , false);
_shape->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable , false);}
```

**With this code work right**

```
    Core::ShapeGroup * t_group = new Core::ShapeGroup();
m_scene->addItem(t_group);
QGraphicsRectItem * t_rect1 = new QGraphicsRectItem(135,-25,100,100);
t_rect1->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
t_rect1->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable | QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
t_rect1->setBrush(Qt::red);
m_scene->addItem(t_rect1);
QGraphicsRectItem * t_rect2 = new QGraphicsRectItem(50,50,100,100);
t_rect2->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
t_rect2->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable | QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
t_rect2->setBrush(Qt::blue);
m_scene->addItem(t_rect2);


t_group->addToShapeGroup(t_rect1);
t_group->addToShapeGroup(t_rect2);
```

**But not with this**

```
    Shape::Ellipse * t_ellipse1 =new  Shape::Ellipse();
m_scene->addItem(t_ellipse1);
t_ellipse1->moveBy(158,-69);

Shape::Ellipse * t_ellipse2 =new  Shape::Ellipse();
m_scene->addItem(t_ellipse2);

t_group->addToShapeGroup(t_ellipse1);
t_group->addToShapeGroup(t_ellipse2);
```

**The next image represent 2 QgraphicsRectItem item ShapeGroup (the pen with  color blue and style Dash represent)**
[Using QGraphicsrectItem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKjXS.png)

[in this case I  have two ellipse into ShapeGroup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1dD5.png)

Comment: The question, as it is formulated, leaves your expectations and your results a mystery. You need to add code and images if you hope to get your problem resolved.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"...passing the figures the group does not correctly represent the shape of the figure..."* ? By the way, your `Ellipse::shape()` method returns always a *circular shape*, not elliptical one.

Comment: Tomas, the figures are displayed, the problem is the selection of them, since the shape of the ShapeGroup class should contain all the shapes of the figures it contains, provides the QGraphicsRectItem and functions but with the Ellipse class if I update the position the shape of this is not updated.